# Question on Plist

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

I need to retrieve 6 questions from a plist and check the answer if is correct from the plist itself??

i will use a QR code scanner api to scan for answer, the api will covert to a string and read from the plist to check if the answer is correct... is there any tutorial or references for me to look @ ??

In my plist there is: question ~ Dictionary with the following strings:

NumberOfOption ~ which define if the question is a multiple choice or a QR code question Question ~ question itself Answer ~ Answer itself Option 1 ~ 4 ~ if it is a multiple choice question

Thanks in advance for answering my questions, i appreciated it

cheers

Desmond